# Worklight Geo fencing Dynamically update trigger locations

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, geofencing, worklight-studio, worklight-geolocation

I need to create a geofence trigger , after the creation if the user Left the area i want to call 1 API after that i need to create another trigger with current(new) location info and so on

So far i tried 
    function getFirstPositionAndTrack() {
    alert('Click OK to proceed to acquire starting position');

```
// use GPS to get the user's location
var geoPolicy = WL.Device.Geo.Profiles.LiveTracking();
geoPolicy.timeout = 60000; // set timeout to 1 minute
geoPolicy.maximumAge = 10000; // allow to use a position that is 10 seconds old

// note: to see at high-accuracy, change RoughTracking above to LiveTracking

// get the user's current position
WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(
        function(pos) {
            // when we receive the position, we display it and start on-going acquisition
            displayPosition(pos);


            var triggers = {
                Geo: {
                    posChange: { 
                        type: "PositionChange",
                        callback: function(deviceContext) {
                                displayPosition(deviceContext.Geo);
                            }
                    },

                    leftArea: { 
                        type: "Exit",
                        circle: {
                            longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
                            latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                            radius: 200
                        },
                        callback: function() {
                            alert('Left the area');
                           **/* here i will call one api , And i need to create another trigger dynamically with updated position info */**
                        }
                    },

                    dwellArea: { // alert when we have stayed in the vicinity for 3 seconds
                        type: "DwellInside",
                        circle: {
                            longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
                            latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                            radius: 50
                        },
                        dwellingTime: 3000,
                        callback: function() {
                            alert('Still in the vicinity');

                        }
                    }
                }   
            };

            WL.Device.startAcquisition({ Geo: geoPolicy }, triggers, { Geo: alertOnGeoAcquisitionErr } );
        },
        function(geoErr) {
            alertOnGeoAcquisitionErr(geoErr);
            // try again:
            getFirstPositionAndTrack();
        },
        geoPolicy
    );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to change the triggers that you have. You can either create a new triggers object, or update the existing one. Note that your trigger callback can receive the [current device context](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.html?lang=en) as a parameter, which then gives you access to the current position. Then make another call to WL.Device.startAcquisition(...) again, this time passing in the new/updated triggers object.